# How to add double quotes automatically, converting list of strings as comma separated value

Tags: java

Assume that I have a list of Strings.

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
s.add("one");
s.add("two");
s.add("three");
```

When I use `StringUtils.join(",", s)` it gives me the result as

```
"one, two, three"
```

Whereas I need the output as

```
"one","two","three"
```

We don't like to use Guava utility as the project is not in active state.

Is it possible via Apache Commons utility?

How can I achieve this via utility instead of writing my own logic to do the same?

Comment: "writing own logic" in this case is the fastest way to achieve the goal. It's only 3 lines ...

Comment: You forgot to tell _why_ you want the strings written in this way. Do you need to generate Java code, or JavaScript code, or a CSV file?

Comment: I need to pass them in a mongo DB query when using $in operator

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it in two steps with `StringUtils` only,

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
s.add("one");
s.add("two");
s.add("three");

String step1 = StringUtils.join(s, "\", \"");// Join with ", "
String step2 = StringUtils.wrap(step1, "\"");// Wrap step1 with "

System.out.println(step2);
```

Output,

```
"one", "two", "three"
```

---

## **BUT**

> *I need to pass them in a mongo DB query when using $in operator*

For `mongodb` query you don't need to build it this way, specifically in case of `$in` you can query documents in following way,

```
BasicDBObject yourInQuery = new BasicDBObject();
yourInQuery.put("in_column", new BasicDBObject("$in", yourList));
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(yourInQuery);
```

Please read more about this in following link,

- [Find or Query Data with Java Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/java/query/)

Comment: Is this is not an expensive operation when the list contains more strings?

Comment: @Kathiresa Yes, the only _extra_ operation will be to wrap the joined String with `"`. In step 1 you will have `one", "two", "three` and in step 2 you just need to wrap it with `"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot and it solves the problem. Both had a good clarity.. Good one TAsk...

Answer (score 5):

```
String joined = s.stream()
    .map(plain -> '"' + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(plain) + '"')
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

The idea is to first convert each of the strings to a properly quoted representation and then join them.

You have to decide for yourself which escaping function to use. And just in case you are generating a CSV file, you should really use some `CsvWriter` class.

Comment: I need to pass them in a mongo DB query when using $in operator

Comment: Doesn't mongodb has query parameters? That looks like a smell.

Comment: Please see this JB Nizet - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 2):

Simply by using [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-):

Docs example:

```
 String message = String.join("-", "Java", "is", "cool");
 // message returned is: "Java-is-cool"
```

You can do something like:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
res = String.join(",", list).replaceAll("([^,]+)", "\"$1\"");
```

`replaceAll` accepts a regex that catches everything that's not "," (your delimiter), and surrounds it with double quotes.

If your input contains a comma, you can first iterate on the arraylist and add quotes to each element, and only then use `join`.

Comment: desired output:
`"one","two","three"`

Comment: i think `regex` can play some important part here

Comment: What if the strings contain commas as well?

Comment: Is this is not an expensive operation when list contains more strings?

Comment: @RolandIllig I assume it doesn't, your approach is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it using **Java 8** without any third-party utility.

```
String csvWithQuotes = s.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\",\"", "\"", "\""));
```

The logic used here is to use **","** as the separator and then prefix and suffix it with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the first two answers:

```
var s = new ArrayList<String>();
s.add("one");
s.add("two");
s.add("three");

var resultString = s.stream()
                    .map(s -> StringUtils.wrap(s, "\"")
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Note: this uses Java 8 and apache commons.

Answer (score 0):

The old way..put this utility method ,

```
 private static final String DOUBLE_QUOTE_ESCAPED = "\"";
    public static final String SYMBOL_COMMA = ",";
    
    public static String joinWithDoubleQuotedElements(List<String> s, String joinSymbol) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 1;
        for (String val : s) {
            builder.append(DOUBLE_QUOTE_ESCAPED).append(val).append(DOUBLE_QUOTE_ESCAPED);
            if (count != s.size()) {
            builder.append(joinSymbol);
            }
            ++count;
        }
        return builder.toString();
        }
```

Call to `joinWithDoubleQuotedElements(s, SYMBOL_COMMA)` will give you desired result.